# Get powershell script text that is executed before calling System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke()

Tags: c#, powershell

Is there a way to get text of executed powershell script in C#.

For example:

```
using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    Collection<PSObject> result;

    // psScript object is script text loaded from some .ps1 file
    powerShellInstance.AddScript(psScript);

    //parameters object is list of passed parameters
    powerShellInstance.AddParameters(parameters);

    result = powerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

Can we get executed script text anywhere in above code so we could just copy it and try to execute it directly in powershell.

EDIT:

My .ps1 script file looks like this:

```
param($CustomerPrimaryO365Domain, $AdminUsername, $AdminPassword, $Domain)
#####################################################################################################################################################################
function Get-CustomerDomain()
#####################################################################################################################################################################
{
    $O365Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $AdminUsername,(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $AdminPassword)
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $O365Cred
    $tenID=(Get-MSOLPartnerContract -Domain $CustomerPrimaryO365Domain).tenantId.guid
    Get-MsolDomain -DomainName $Domain -TenantId $tenID

}
Import-Module MSOnline
Get-CustomerDomain
```

But when it is executed it needs to look something like this:

```
#####################################################################################################################################################################
function Get-CustomerDomain()
#####################################################################################################################################################################
{
    $O365Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "MyAdmin@test.test",(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String "testpassword")
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $O365Cred
    $tenID=(Get-MSOLPartnerContract -Domain "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com").tenantId.guid
    Get-MsolDomain -DomainName "testdomain.info" -TenantId $tenID

}
Import-Module MSOnline
Get-CustomerDomain
```

Is there a way to get "executed" script from powerShellInstance object.

Comment: Is not `psScript` what you want?

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: So, you just want to cut `param` block?

Comment: Why not just pass the parameters?